# Get the reduced or increased working hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I need to get the reduced or increased working hours, starter and leavers from employee list for previous compare to current month for the last 12 month.

The problem I have is I don't get any leavers which was on previous month but current month the working hours is null so called leavers.

[image]

here is what I have tried:

```
WITH CURRENTbase AS
(
    SELECT Employee, Work_hrs,monthdate
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE monthlydate >= '2020-mar-01'
),
PREVIOUSbase AS
(
    SELECT Employee, Work_hrs,monthdate
    DATEADD(MONTH,1,monthdate) monthdate
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE  monthdate >= '2020-mar-01'
)
SELECT 
    B.*, A.*,
    A.monthdate,
    ISNULL(B.Work_hrs,0) PreviousHRS,
    ISNULL(A.Work_hrs,0) CurrentHRS,
    CASE 
        WHEN b.Work_hrs is null THEN 'Starter'
        WHEN a.Work_hrs is null THEN 'Leaver'
        WHEN a.Work_hrs > b.Work_hrs THEN 'hrs_Increase'
        WHEN b.Work_hrs > a.Work_hrs THEN 'hrs_Decrease'
        WHEN b.Work_hrs = a.Work_hrs THEN 'NoChange'
        ELSE 'Check'
    END Status
FROM CURRENTbase A

LEFT JOIN PREVIOUSbase B 
    ON A.Employee = B.Employee AND A.monthdate = B.monthdate

WHERE a.CensusDate >= '2020-apr-01'

GROUP BY
    A.monthdate,
    ISNULL(B.Work_hrs,0) PreviousHRS,
    ISNULL(A.Work_hrs,0) CurrentHRS,
    CASE 
        WHEN b.Work_hrs is null THEN 'Starter'
        WHEN a.Work_hrs is null THEN 'Leaver'
        WHEN a.Work_hrs > b.Work_hrs THEN 'hrs_Increase'
        WHEN b.Work_hrs > a.Work_hrs THEN 'hrs_Decrease'
        WHEN b.Work_hrs = a.Work_hrs THEN 'NoCHange'
        ELSE 'check'
    END
```

Comment: Also please tell us how you would know whether EMP1 had left or just had zero hours in the month?

Comment: Hi Filburt, I'd like to see the previous  and current working hours value mainly, then i can create a case statement for the status myself. many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query if you use MS SQL SERVER 2012 or above, adopt the `order by` to suite your needs

```
SELECT *
  ,CASE 
      WHEN LEAD(WORKING_HOURS) OVER (
              PARTITION BY Employee ORDER BY Year DESC
                  ,Month DESC
              ) IS NULL
          THEN 'Starter'
      WHEN LEAD(WORKING_HOURS) OVER (
            PARTITION BY Employee ORDER BY Year ASC
                ,Month ASC
            ) IS NULL
        THEN 'Leaver'
      WHEN LEAD(WORKING_HOURS) OVER (
            PARTITION BY Employee ORDER BY Year ASC
                ,Month ASC
            ) > LEAD(WORKING_HOURS) OVER (
            PARTITION BY Employee ORDER BY Year DESC
                ,Month DESC
            )
        THEN 'hrs_Increase'
      WHEN LEAD(WORKING_HOURS) OVER (
            PARTITION BY Employee ORDER BY Year DESC
                ,Month DESC
            ) > LEAD(WORKING_HOURS) OVER (
            PARTITION BY Employee ORDER BY Year ASC
                ,Month ASC
            )
        THEN 'hrs_Decrease'
      WHEN LEAD(WORKING_HOURS) OVER (
            PARTITION BY Employee ORDER BY Year DESC
                ,Month DESC
            ) = LEAD(WORKING_HOURS) OVER (
            PARTITION BY Employee ORDER BY Year ASC
                ,Month ASC
            )
        THEN 'NoCHange'
      ELSE 'check'
      END
 FROM (
     SELECT Employee
        ,MONTH(monthdate) Month
        ,YEAR(monthdate) Year
        ,SUM(Work_hrs) AS WORKING_HOURS
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY Employee
       ,MONTH(monthdate)
       ,YEAR(monthdate)
  ) a
```

Comment: Dourayd thanks for your help but this is not what I am asking sorry if i have not explained it correctly. the problem I have it is for those customer left the value is 0 and not showing in next month value so I can not assign them to as a leaver.

Comment: If i did understand you, you have a problem identifying leavers. if that so normally lead would give you NULL if there is no data for next month. if not can you please explain further or give us based on the data you gave a desired output.